# Where did my clan go?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Something very screwed up and very unfortunate has happened. I was the leader of a clan with around 45 members and all of a sudden I noticed I was in no clan. I had no messages in my inbox. My clan castle is still full of troops and loot (as how I remember it should be). Is the game currently glitching? Any ideas what happened?

I have a theory. After upgrading to T.H. 8 I stopped 3 staring as many bases. I think my trophy count is too low to be in my own clan. Is this possible? How can I fix it? I was working really hard to fix this clan up and it really pisses me off if I got kicked out. Can a leader be kicked out? There is no mention in the inbox.

Comment: I recommend that you contact supercell because I don't think that it is possible to get kicked out of your own clan.Probably a bug.

Comment: Can you still find your clan and did you try to join if you found it?

Comment: @Jerry I did but it said my trophy count was too low. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: @Celeritas This happens if the current leader or co-leader(s) have set a minimum trophy join requirement to the clan. You will need to have at least the quoted trophies to be able to join it. About the underlying problem though, I have not heard of such thing. Could it be someone got into your account without you knowing and make you leave the clan?

Comment: It's definitely a bug as it fixed itself now.

Comment: For future reference, you can't get kicked from your clan if you're below the trophy limit. Only people who try to join have to be above the trophy limit.

Comment: @zack1544 how do you report the bug? It's happened to 2 more clan mates.

Comment: @Celeritas just contact supercell to report the bug( contact info on their website)

Comment: @Celeritas May be you accidentally leader some one else since one person can be leader. And he kicked you out. Or If you left clan the co leader automatically becomes leader.

Answer (score 1):

Either it is a bug, or someone hacked into your account and removed it. I would suggest to contact with supercell if you are certain no one logged into your account to do that. Additionally, you can search with your 'clan name' or 'clan id' to see if that clan is still available. Hopefully it helped.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the game. You shouldn't be able to get kicked from your own clan for having too few trophies.

Contact Supercell support or just wait for it to fix itself.

Comment: Answer derived from comments on the question.